# Build a 3D least squares distance matrix without loops?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to build a three dimensional matrix out of three vectors where I take the least squares distance between each element of each vector as the entries of the matrix.

For example for the 3d matrix d,

```
d(m,n,o)=(vec1(m)-vec2(n))^2+(vec1(m)-vec3(o))^2+(vec2(n)-vec1(o))^2
```

I am currently doing this with a triple for loop:

```
d=zeros(N,M,O);
for o=1:O
    for n=1:N
        for m=1:M
            d(n,m,o)=(((t(n)-r(m))^2)+((t(n)-z(o))^2)+((r(m)-z(o))^2));
        end
    end
end
```

My question is whether there is a quicker, cleverer way to do this for instance for a 2d version of this I could use:

```
%for n=1:N
%    for m=1:M
%        d(n,m)=(t(n)-r(m))^2;
%    end
%end
d=(repmat(t(:),1,M)-repmat(r(:)',N,1)).^2; %this replaces the nested for loops from       above Thanks Georg Schmitz
```

Whoever Georg Schmitz is came up with a way to use repmat to replace the double for loops in the 2d version. I could of course adapt this method and replace my triple for loops with one for loop that repeats the repmat method (o) number of times, But I feel like there should be a way to do this without loops.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed vectorize the calculation:

```
%# properly reshape the vectors
vec1 = vec1(:); %# n-by-1
vec2 = reshape(vec2,1,[]); %# 1-by-m
vec3 = reshape(vec3,1,1,[]); %# 1-by-1-by-o 

%# use bsxfun to efficiently replicate the arrays
d = bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@plus,...
    bsxfun(@minus,vec1,vec2).^2,...
    bsxfun(@minus,vec2,vec3).^2)),...
    bsxfun(@minus,vec3,vec1).^2));
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, I considered using bsxfun but couldn't figure out a way around the two argument max.

Answer (score 0):

You should try pdist or pdist2 depending on your needs. pdist computes inner distances, while pdist2 computes a pairwise distance matrix.